# QGIS visualization of Pleiades image is gray and fixed only when copying style

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, google-earth-engine, visualisation, rgb

I have airbus Pleiades images which has 4 bands - B , G , R and NIR.

The image was reprojected (4326) and resampled (50cm) using GEE as following:

```
    task = ee.batch.Export.image.toCloudStorage(
        image = my_img,
        bucket = 'my_bucket',
        fileNamePrefix = 'imgs/pleiades_reproject_resmapled/'+name+'.tif',
        region=my_img.geometry(),
        scale = 0.5,
        crs = "EPSG:4326",
        maxPixels=1e12
        )
```

(I had to do this for reason that is not relevant here)

I'm trying to apply RGB visualization on the image using QGIS, but for some reason I keep getting gray image. However, when I open the original image before it was reprojected and resampled , and I apply the RGB visualization it works. Moreover, when I copy the style of the original image and then paste it on the reprojected image, it works and I get the RGB image.
However, I don't want to be depended on copying style and I want to understand why I get the image gray.

This is how I visualize the image that is not reprojected (the one I get as RGB):

[image]
[image]

The reprojected image:
[image]

when I manually insert the values for the reproject image, I still get gray image :
[image]

[image]

I realized here that the bands names is the only different thing I can find , however, I am sure that b2 is red and not blue, b1 is green and b0 is blue. And I have also changed the order and checked and it still gray.

Histogram of the original image :
[image]

Histogram of the reprojected image:
[image]

When I open the image on GEE platform, with 98% stretching twice, it shows RGB as requested.

**My goal is to understand why I can't visualize the post-processed image using RGB visualization , why only pasting the style worked, and how can I fix it and not being dependent on copy visualization .**

Comment: Not sure about that but you may try to change the "Min / Max Value Settings" to made sure it use the actual Min/Max on the whole raster with actual value (on my screen your gray picture look like a very desaturated color image rather than grayscale)...

Comment: @J.R I have just checked it, it uses the whole raster

Comment: Trying expanding the `Min / Value Settings` and applying a % clip to the values. As J.R. suggests, it looks like the colours are being stretched to values much too high.

Comment: Can you share the Image you've donwnloaded?